# Setting Border.Child throws ArgumentException

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I am using the Glyphs control in my WP7 app (I don't know yet whether it is important that it is Glyphs). The Glyphs is used by setting it as the child of a Border element. Sometimes - it is not yet clear exactly when - the setter of the Border.Child property throws an ArgumentException. The message does not say anything special and there is no InnerException. The call stack is the following:

```
at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
at MS.Internal.XcpImports.SetValue(IManagedPeerBase obj, DependencyProperty property, DependencyObject doh)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty property, DependencyObject doh)
at System.Windows.Controls.Border.set_Child(UIElement value)
```

Is there any way to debug or diagnose what could be the underlying problem?

Comment: The code creating and setting up the Glyphs is quite complex, and I could not reproduce the issue in any simpler situation, so I can't really post sample code. However, the line causing the exception is simply something like this: `this.myBorder.Child = myGlyphs;`